# io.sockets.manager.rooms leading 'undefined' in rooms

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I use socket.io rooms:

```
socket.join("myroom/1");
```

but when i call

```
io.sockets.manager.rooms
```

to get list of rooms, it return:

```
undefined/myroom/1": [

    "MQJzMTtpzKsL2rrOXCKX"

]
```

why room name has **undefined** leading?

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem is i use '`namespace`' keyword as my variable `(socket.namespace='blabla')` so it return `'undefined'`